# php numeric row list per pages

Tags: php

i trey numeric list, but list as per pages.

my code:

```
$results_per_page = 2;
if (isset($_GET["p"])) { $page  = $_GET["p"]; } else { $page=1; };
$start_from = ($page-1) * $results_per_page;
$conn = mysqli_connect("asd", "asd", "asdd", "asdsadasd");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `profile_tournaments` ORDER BY `exp` DESC LIMIT ".$start_from.", ".$results_per_page.";";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>".$row["username"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["exp"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["wins"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["loses"]."</td>
        <td>Trofeus</td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

how i can do?

i want:

Page 1

- 1 user1
- 2 user2
- 3 user3

Page 2

- 4 user4
- 5 user5
- 6 user6

i try $number = $number+1;

but on change page starting 1...

sorry for my bad english, and thanks for help

Comment: `limit $limit, $offset`

Comment: Please add more detail, And describe your problem + delete unnecessary parts of your code

Comment: lets try, i want numeric row lines, but on change pages, starting 1 and i want example page 1 = 1,2,3,4,5 | page 2 = 6,7,8,9,10 etc etc